# Add New line item in Sales Order Using Suite Script 2.0

Tags: netsuite

I want to add new line item in Sales Order based on the particular Inventory item I select. The new line item should be loaded with the existing item record details in it. For this, I used the below code, but its not working;

```
function recalc(type)
{
    var itemId = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item'); //Get the Item ID
    if(itemId == 16340) //Repair Cost
    {
        alert ("Hi");
        //Insert item
        nlapiSelectNewLineItem('item');
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'item', 330); //Repair Cost
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', 1);
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'amount', '0.00');
        nlapiCommitLineItem('item');

    }
    return true;
}
```

**Can somebody help to rewrite the code in SS 2.0.**

Comment: Here's a video describing how to work with sublists in 2.0: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n05OiKYDxhI

Answer (score 4):

You can refer [SuiteScript 1.0 to SuiteScript 2.0 API Map](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4752724744.html) for NetSuite SuiteScript 1 to 2 API.
As for your question, you can use the following

```
function recalc(type) {
    currentRecord.selectLine({ sublistId: 'item', line: LINE_NO });

    var itemId = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item' }); // Get the Item ID

    if (itemId == 16340) {//Repair Cost
        // Insert item
        currentRecord.selectNewLine({ sublistId: 'item' });

        currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'item', value: 330 });//Repair Cost
        currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'quantity', value: 1 });//Repair Cost
        currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'amount', value: '0.00' });//Repair Cost

        currentRecord.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item' });
    }

    return true;
}
```